# convert pdf to image using pdf url (pdf2image)

Tags: python, django

```
images_from_path = convert_from_path(settings.MEDIA_ROOT+'file/some.pdf',100)
images_from_path[0].save(settings.MEDIA_ROOT+'image/'+'a.jpg'))
```

I can get or save the images like this. How do I use a pdf file-url(https://example.com/xyz.pdf) to get the images?

Answer (score 2):

Fetch the data using your favourite HTTP library:

```
import requests, pdf2image
pdf = requests.get('https://example.com/xyz.pdf')
pdf2image.convert_from_bytes(pdf.raw.read())
```

Comment: it says 'Unable to get page count'

Comment: just put page_count as a random large number. Works for me.

Comment: Rather than `pdf2image.convert_from_bytes(pdf.raw.read())`, this works:
`images = convert_from_bytes(pdf.content)`

Comment: @JessieinAg: your solution in the comment should figure as an answer, it is the only one that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

incrementing @fqrt's answer we need to add stream=True in requests.get

```
pdf = requests.get('https://example.com/xyz.pdf', stream=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just summing up to save the next guy some time:

```
import requests, pdf2image
pdf = requests.get('https://example.com/xyz.pdf', stream=True)
images = pdf2image.convert_from_bytes(pdf.content)
```